# Is there a way to use a downloaded (xml-esque) file in an extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to write an emusic download manager extension for Chrome.  This would essentially involve parsing the .emx file (xml-esque) downloaded from the site to get the temporary music file URL.

I've gone through everything I can find online about extensions working with downloads, but the problem comes in that the .emx file isn't directly accessible from the web.  The link to download it seems to pass through a counter for your account so that it can deduct the cost, and then it pushes a file 0.emx to be downloaded.  It doesn't seem to work with any hotlinking, even copying and pasting the button's destination URL into the same browser tab.

I think the only way to get the file is to wait for the 0.emx file to be pushed.  Is there any way I can use an extension to intercept that file before it goes to the downloads folder or use it after it's already downloaded?

Thanks!